# You need Java 11 or higher to build your app with this version of Gradle

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, java-11

I am having this issue on mac
[image]

Everything was working fine untill i tried to run a flutter code i bought from Codecanyon and started having this issue, which i tried so many fix which i saw online and will list them bellow, but now even the new flutter projects i create now give same issue

Steps:
i have installed java 11 and 16 as well
[image]

then tried to change the defaul jdk version using

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11.0.17`
```

and

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)
```

then when i run `java -version`  on the terminal i get the report bellow
[image]

which i believe means i have succefuly changed it (I haved tried using bash, switched to Zsh and now back to bash) but it's still not working

Also tried to change it via the IDE from some solutions i saw here on stackOverflow but from the android-studio> Prefrences> Build, Execution, Deployment> Gradle the section is not showing until i try the File> Project Structure> Project and select JDK 11
[image]

Still not working, even installed the latest version of Android Studio, still didn't fix the issue, and i had to install the old version again since my emulator stopped working after the update

Have been battling this for some weeks to a month now, have checked multiple solutions here and on github but still can't get a solution that works

Comment: So many things here, but first off, JAVA_HOME doesn't determine which `java` runs on the command line, that's controlled by PATH; second, JAVA_HOME is for a path, not a command

Comment: @MikeKim so what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Trying for weeks what later worked for me was going to
Project_File>Android>build.gradle file and changing

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

To:

```
...
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
...
```

and i just run `./gradlew clean build` and then run the project, everything now working fine

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

search for `gradle` in preferences and then select the correct **Gradle JDK**

[image]

Comment: I can't find that section when i open the Prefrence>Build, Execute, Deployment>gradle ... it only stops at "Generat *iml files for modules..." no Gradle Projects section... i have also updated the Andriod studio and it's still not showing

Answer (score 0):

The current flutter version does not support this project. You can open the Gradle configuration file embedded in the current flutter version to view the Gradle information.

##### open android>app>build.gradle line 24

- apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
- open terminal run "whereis flutter" you can get flutter install path
- open "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle" file

##### You will see the gradle version used by the current flutter version and current java compile version

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        /* When bumping, also update ndkVersion above. */
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    }
}

android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Comment: I have also tried changing this to ```JavaVersion.VERSION_11``` but it's still not working... or what do you suggest?

Comment: I think you can try delete gradle cache and reinstall gradle plugin      <br> ./gradlew clean build

Comment: @bakbeom please how should I do that on Mac?

Comment: terminal goto project>android. and run ./gradlew clean build

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Open **android/app/build.gradle**

Change from this:

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

To this:

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
```